# Error while installing jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am encountering the below error while installing jupyterlab using pip.

```
c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\include\pyconfig.h(207): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

I did see some posts like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691564/running-cython-in-windows-x64-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ba

They talk about installing Windows 10 SDK which is ~ 2.3GB. IMHO, I felt that Windows 10 SDK should not be a dependency for **jupyterlab**. But, please correct me if I am wrong here!

Comment: Did you run the error you get (`Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h'`) through a web search (Google, duck duck go, startpage, whatever floats your boat)? If so, did you find anything which you've tried? Why did it not work? If not, could you please spend 10 minutes searching for it to see if this issue has occurred with someone in the past?

Comment: I did search and went through a few links but none worked. Will mention those things in an edit in the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Otherwise others might spend time suggesting things you've tried already and didn't work. Although, as you have not actually tried the solution (Windows 10 SDK), perhaps you can do that first to see if that resolves the issue? If 2.3GB is really an impossible to download filesize for your, then perhaps you can focus your question on lightweight Jupyterlab alternatives (of course, after including research on *that*).